# Threading with CPort

Tags: multithreading, delphi, port, pascal

I'm trying to write a simple [CPort](http://sourceforge.net/projects/comport/) application in delphi.

I want it to listen to a port, upon receiving a message, it will wait 4 seconds then send a string in response.

```
unit Tests.Mocks.Refractometer;

interface

uses
  CPort,
  Classes
  ;

type
  TRefractometerMock = class
    strict private
      MockRunThread : TThread;
      ComPort : TComPort;
      ComDataPacket: TComDataPacket;
    public
      procedure Open;
      procedure HandlePacket(Sender : TObject; const Str : String);

      constructor Create; overload;
      constructor Create(BaudRate : TBaudRate; Port : String); overload;
      destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

implementation

uses
  SysUtils,
  StrUtils
  ;

procedure TRefractometerMock.HandlePacket(Sender : TObject; const Str : String);
begin
    MockRunThread.Start;    
end;

procedure TRefractometerMock.Open;
begin
    ComPort.Open;
end;

constructor TRefractometerMock.Create(BaudRate : TBaudRate; Port : String);
begin
    Self.Create;
    Self.ComPort.Port := Port;
    Self.ComPort.BaudRate := BaudRate;
end;

constructor TRefractometerMock.Create;
begin
    inherited;
    ComPort := TComPort.Create(nil);
    ComDataPacket := TComDataPacket.Create(nil);

    ComDataPacket.ComPort := ComPort;
    ComDataPacket.OnPacket := HandlePacket;

    MockRunThread := TThread.CreateAnonymousThread
    (
        procedure
        begin
            Sleep(4000);
            Self.ComPort.WriteStr('nD=1.33308;');
        end
    );
end;

destructor TRefractometerMock.Destroy;
begin
    if Assigned(Self.ComPort)  then FreeAndNil(Self.ComPort);
    if Assigned(ComDataPacket) then FreeAndNil(ComDataPacket);
    if Assigned(MockRunThread) then FreeAndNil(MockRunThread);

    inherited;
end;

end.
```

---

using this unit I can use the following code to

Start listening

```
RefractometerMock := TRefractometerMock.Create(TBaudRate.br9600, 'COM7');
try
    RefractometerMock.Open;

    Sleep(8000);

finally
    FreeAndNil(RefractometerMock);
end;
```

Also note that I'm using [com0com](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/) to create a bridge between ports `COM6` and `COM7`.

I'm sending a putty message on port `COM6`

[image: putty]

The problem is that even though I have sent a message with putty, the `HandlePacket` method does not get called until the `TRefractometerMock` object is freed.

First
[image: Start]

Then

[image: handle]

Then

[image: anon]

Finally

[image: error]

[image: thread handle]

I'm not even sure how this is possible since I thought this object had been destroyed.

Comment: You did not start the thread. A anonymous thread is created as suspended. You need to call MockRunThread.Start;

Comment: @AllenBauer  `MockRunThread.Start` gets called in the `HandlePacket` function. This should get invoked when a packet is received from the com port. At least, that's what I want to happen.

Comment: @sav: This combination of CPort and TAnonymousThread is a useful reference. Could you post your corrected code with LU RD's mods? Thanks for the pointer to com0com too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are blocking the main thread by `Sleep(8000)`. This means that the com port driver is not able to call the `HandlePacket` method.

When the sleep is over, it is too late to handle anything, since everything is freed.

Since you are handling the life time of the anonymous thread, you should set the `FreeOnTerminate` property to false. And free the com port after the anonymous thread.

Use a timer instead of the `Sleep()` call.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to do this with a timer. Perhaps if I add this code to a form instead of calling it from a console application

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any settings for ComDataPacket. From help: `Packet ends when one of stop conditions occurs`. Did you define these stop conditions?
Have you checked data receiving using ComDataPacket in simple standalone application, without intermediate class?

BTW, it seems that TTimer could do the work, thread is not necessary here.

Answer (score 0):

Since Brian Frost wants the code here it is, this is too big to fit in a comment.

Create a simple form

```
type
  TFrmMockRefrac = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    RefractometerMock : TRefractometerMock;
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  FrmMockRefrac: TFrmMockRefrac;
```

---

Handle creating and destruction without the `Sleep` function

```
procedure TFrmMockRefrac.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
    RefractometerMock := TRefractometerMock.Create(TBaudRate.br9600, 'COM7');
    RefractometerMock.Open;
end;

procedure TFrmMockRefrac.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
    FreeAndNil(RefractometerMock);
end;
```